# Why was my accepted answer deleted when it answered OP's question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

My answer to [Is it allowed to fetch businesses from Places API and save them? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74914320/is-it-allowed-to-fetch-businesses-from-places-api-and-save-them) which was accepted by the author was vote deleted 2 days ago (06/01/2022) after a discussion in the comments 4 days ago (04/01/2022) which was cleaned by both parties (me and the other user):
[image]

According to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), an answer may be deleted if it **do not fundamentally answer the question**.

My answer was posted after I first flagged the question as a duplicate of [Storing Google Places API data - is it allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344191/storing-google-places-api-data-is-it-allowed) (which stands unlocked as of today) and the OP said that the linked answer does not answer their question.

My answer answered OP's question and the answer was accepted by the OP.

> The short answer is that **no**, it is not allowed to pre-fetch, cache, or **store** any Content, see 3.2.3 Restrictions Against Misusing the Services in https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/

What warrants my accepted answer to be deleted when the [linked answer of similar fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14344523/20073186) which was not marked as a duplicate by OP, still stands?

Comment: Was the new answer really that useful if another answer says almost the same thing?

Comment: According to the OP, it was useful to them @Dharman: "_No, because my app has a difference when it comes to fetching compared to something that the OP said in their post from the link above._", "_Thanks for the answer, it looks like they indeed do not accept any kind of way of storing their data. Looks like I got to move on to another third party solution. Thank you._"

Comment: An OP is often wrong, so I would take whatever they say with a grain of salt. From the perspective of a random visitor, your answer just repeats what was said before

Comment: FYI I also closed the old question. It doesn't seem suitable for Stack Overflow at all.

Comment: @NoraSöderlund *which was cleaned by both parties (me and the other user)*: I'm not reading MrUpsidown's last comment to you as anything other than sarcasm.

Comment: I also closed several additional questions in the [tag:google-places-api] tag that were asking for similar information. There are probably quite a few more. Such questions are asking for a *legal* interpretation of a third party's terms of service and/or contracts under which you and/or the question author are operating. Such questions are *not* programming questions. They are *legal* questions.

Comment: @Daedalus cleaned as in deleted by ourselves.

Comment: For future discussion (because this will happen again), there is no need to continuously refer to the answer being accepted as if that is some kind of argument. On Stack Overflow questions and answers exist to help the many, so the fact that an answer helped one person (the OP) is pretty insignificant in the bigger picture. Quality votes are what truly matters, besides other factors such as an answer providing unique information.

Comment: It is some kind of argument, though. It would be naive to say it isn't. If the one person who did need help with the question found the answer useful, and the ones that _did not find it useful_ did not have the question to begin with, it's not a correct comparison. I've agreed with everything else that has been said here, but I can't agree with what you just said.

Answer (score 12):

As one of the people that voted to delete the answer, I can give some reasoning.

Question itself was off topic and as such it doesn't belong to the site. Because it had an accepted answer that would prevent question from being automatically deleted when closed and having negative score.

At the time I voted for the deletion of the answer, question was not eligible for casting delete votes and since I could cast vote to delete the answer, I voted to delete the answer instead.

It is all part of the cleanup process. If something does not belong to the site, it is better to be cleaned up sooner rather than later. In that regard it does not matter whether question was deleted or answer was deleted as long as final outcome is that both posts are gone.

Please note that there are many posts that don't belong on the site and that some might be open, but that does not mean they belong here. Also people that participate in cleaning and moderating the site are few and we don't have time to babysit each and every post waiting for it to be eligible for some action, so we will perform cleanup actions that make the most sense at the given moment.

Answer (score 8):

*Why was my accepted answer deleted ...* - because three people voted to delete it, that's how community moderation works.

Also from [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

> Answers can also be deleted by the community. Moderators can delete any answer, and [trusted community members](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) can vote to delete answers that have a score of -1 or lower (3 votes will result in deletion).

As to why those people voted that way, we can only speculate.